# Assigning Roles to User in SharePoint using PnPCore

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, azure-functions, pnp-core-sdk

I have the below issue which I fight for an extensive amount of time:

I develop a small Azure Function that accepts information for a SharePoint site and grants a Contribute role to certain user. What I face as problem is that even I am adding the role and user to the specific list item whenever I try to access that resource I am seeing: `You cannot access this right now Your sign-in was successful but does not meet the criteria to access this resource. For example, you might be signing in from a browser, app, or location that is restricted by your admin.` error message.

For all the interactions with SharePoint I am using PnPCore library and the code looks like this:

```
using var context = await _contextFactory.CreateContextAsync(new Uri(requestContent.Url));

await context.Web.BreakRoleInheritanceAsync(true, true);

var sharedFolderAsListItem = await context.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Root Folder X");

if (sharedFolderAsListItem != null)
{
    await sharedFolderAsListItem.BreakRoleInheritanceAsync(true, true);

    string userGroupName = $"group-of-users-with-access-{uniqueId}";
    var siteGroupUserGroup = await context.Web.SiteGroups
        .QueryProperties(x => x.Users)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Title == userGroupName);
    
    siteGroupUserGroup ??= await context.Web.SiteGroups.AddAsync(userGroupName);

    var roleDefinitions = (await context.Web.GetAsync(p => p.RoleDefinitions)).RoleDefinitions;
    var contributeRole = roleDefinitions.AsRequested().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Contribute");

    foreach (var user in siteGroupUserGroup.Users)
    {
        var rolesForUser = await sharedFolderAsListItem.GetRoleDefinitionsAsync(user.Id);

        if (rolesForUser == null)
            await sharedFolderAsListItem.AddRoleDefinitionAsync(user.Id, contributeRole);
    }
}
```

The above code executes successfully and I can verify that the next time I run the code if I request the role definitions for the same user(s) over the same resource I see entry with permission type Contributor. Yet, when I log in I try to hit the url of the resource I end up with `You cannot access this right now` error.

Am I missing something? Any suggestions are welcome!

Thank you for your time ^^

Comment: Looks like there's a conditional access policy that is restricting the access even when sign in is successful refer here:- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/getting-error-you-cannot-access-this-right-now/312e070b-5ba9-426e-8fb3-db090b09a88f

Comment: Refer this document to know more about condifguring Conditional access policy and asking your Azure AD global Admin to remove the restriction-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-location